# Pagination: Slow ORDER BY with large LIMIT range

Tags: mysql, performance, index, order-by, percona

I have a forum that run this query to do pagination for category pages:

```
mysql> SELECT  thread.threadid,thread.lastpost, thread.lastposter,
               thread.lastpostid, thread.replycount, 
               IF(thread.views<=thread.replycount,
                  thread.replycount+1, thread.views) AS views
    ->
    ->                 FROM thread AS thread
    ->                 WHERE forumid = 21
    ->                 AND sticky = 0
    ->
    ->                 AND visible IN (0,1,2)
    ->
    ->                 ORDER BY sticky DESC, thread.dateline DESC
    ->                 LIMIT 950000, 25;

    25 rows in set (2.64 sec)
```

The large the limit, the more it takes to complete making the page slow to load.

I have already added indexes, however it doesn't make much difference in performance.

Thus far i have tried rewriting the query using [JOIN](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/) which improves a bit, however i was wondering if there is any better aproach to optimize this query.

Unfortunately i can't use WHERE because threadids aren't sequential.

```
mysql> SELECT  thread.threadid,thread.lastpost, thread.lastposter,
               thread.lastpostid, thread.replycount,
               IF(thread.views<=thread.replycount,
                  thread.replycount+1, thread.views) AS views
    ->                 FROM thread AS thread
    ->                 JOIN (SELECT thread.threadid
    ->                 FROM   thread as thread
    ->                 WHERE forumid = 21
    ->                         AND sticky = 0
    ->                          AND visible IN (0,1,2)
    ->                 ORDER BY sticky DESC, thread.dateline DESC
    ->                 LIMIT 950550, 25) AS O2
    ->                 ON thread.threadid = O2.threadid
    ->                 ORDER BY sticky DESC, thread.dateline DESC
    -> ;

25 rows in set (1.49 sec)
```

### EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | thread | ref  | forumid2_dp | forumid2_dp | 2       | const | 1378739 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The table has 4.5m rows.

### Table schema:

```
| thread | CREATE TABLE `thread` (
  `threadid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `prefixid` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `firstpostid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastpostid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastpost` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forumid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pollid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `open` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `replycount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hiddencount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deletedcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `postusername` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `postuserid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastposter` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateline` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `iconid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notes` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `visible` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sticky` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `votenum` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `votetotal` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attach` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `similar` varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `taglist` mediumtext,
  `vbseo_linkbacks_no` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `autoskip` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `tps_thread_points` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`threadid`),
  KEY `postuserid` (`postuserid`),
  KEY `pollid` (`pollid`),
  KEY `forumid` (`forumid`,`visible`,`sticky`,`lastpost`),
  KEY `lastpost` (`lastpost`,`forumid`),
  KEY `dateline` (`dateline`),
  KEY `prefixid` (`prefixid`,`forumid`),
  KEY `forumid2_dp` (`forumid`,`visible`,`sticky`,`dateline`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4879868 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: (Thanks for providing the details -- it make it possible to write an answer without first asking for more info.)

Answer (score 1):

First, I must ask what the heck `LIMIT 950000, 25` is for?  Is some *human* paginating through a zillion pages?  Or is a search engine doing it?  I can't imagine some human with the patience to go that far, so why even provide the capability??

(Sorry, I get irritated at poorly thought-through UIs.)  Now I will get off my high horse and try to answer your question.

- The reformuation *seemed* to help.  But did you run the timings twice?  It *may* be that the first run did more I/O, leaving data cached for the second.
- The use of the subquery is a common trick, though it is unclear (to me) whether it would help in this case.
- The mixture of `IN` and `ORDER BY` says that no index will work all the way through the `ORDER BY`.  That is, the query cannot be optimized to the point of touching only 950000+25 rows.  (Not that that is much help.)
- The subquery ("derived table") in the second formulation takes advantage of KEY `forumid2_dp` (`forumid`,`visible`,`sticky`,`dateline`) because it is "covering".  (Note: In InnoDB, the PK (`threadid`) is silently appended to every secondary key.)
- What is the `EXPLAIN` for the first formulation?  It should (if the Optimizer is smart enough) act mostly like the second.  But I am not sure.

It is possible to make every page as fast as the first.  See my blog on [*remembering where you left off*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) instead of using `OFFSET`.

A quick fix may be to tell search engines not to follow the links here.